# Spinner setSelected not working properly

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a profile activity where user select there country for the first time ,after that when user wish to change the country he will go to profile activity there he should see the previous selected country in the spinner and then he must be able to select another country from the spinner.
I am trying to update my profile activity ,I have a spinner named country in it..I am using set selected for getting the previous selected value .i am getting the value but when i am trying to change that value its not happening .
The Country_value is string 
Below is the code for spinner :

```
country_adapter_list = new ArrayAdapter(MyProfile.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,Country_listItems);
country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_country);
country.setAdapter(country_adapter_list);

country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
country.setSelection(Country_listItems.indexOf(country_value));
country_data = Country_listItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
});
```

Comment: why **`country.setSelection(Country_listItems.indexOf(country_value));`** inside **`setOnItemSelectedListener`**

Comment: so where Should i use that?

Comment: Whenever you tap any item it automatically sets your selection to that. No need to call setSelection

Comment: @SaraTirmizi i am updating my activity so setselection is for privious selected value

Comment: @ShafinRaza Can you briefly explain what you are trying to achieve? 
see if if you are trying to update your previously selected item , say suppose   "coutry_value" is the previously selected value then instead of calling set selection you need to update `country_value =  Country_listItems.get(position);` and later you can compare it any where in  code even in  `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)` method like if (condition() ) and later at the end of method update your country_value

Comment: @SaraTirmizi please read my question again..hope u will get the idea

Comment: For scenario mentioned in question , upon going profile he must have the selected country reference so after `country.setAdapter(country_adapter_list);` call `country.setSelection(indexOfSelectedCountry);` then on spinner of the onItemSelected udpate your indexOfSelectedCountry , Remember since you can come and go back to the profile activity you should always have index of user's country

Comment: call this method 
  -- "country.setSelection(Country_listItems.indexOf(country_value));" outside country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { this line..

Answer (score 0):

`OnItemSelected()` method will select the item present in list at `position`.
The `setSelection()` will internally call the `onItemSelected()` to set the selected item in the spinner. So calling `setSelection()` inside `onItemselected()` will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, but it will not set selection on Spinner if "country_value" is not found in arraylist that  you set.

[Video Link](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bbi.appsdata.2013/gl_dummy_app/ios/20171122_125919.mp4)

Comment: the country_value is from the string arraylist of spinner

Comment: So it is working correctly, see link in video. What else you think wrong in this. for clarification.

Comment: check the video and tell me what need more

Comment: ankit the video link is blank

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> **adapterView**, View view,int position, long l) {
**adapterView**.setSelection(Country_listItems.indexOf(country_value));
country_data = Country_listItems.get(position);
```

}